# Why pow(10,2)=99 & pow(10,3)=1000?

Tags: c++, pow

*I use codeblock for compilation.*

code:

```
int main(){
int l=pow(10,2);
cout<<l;
return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT-99**

```
int main(){
int l=pow(10,3);
cout<<l;
return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT-1000**

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/. The output of pow(10, 2) is probably something like 99.9999999994 and it truncates to 99 when you convert it to an int

Comment: but why not for **pow(10,3)**?

Comment: Because that one probably ends up being 1000.0000000001. There are inaccuracies in floating point representation. Print out the values as double instead of int to see the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

In short - because of integer truncation.

The function `pow` operates on two **floating-point values** and returns a **floating-point** value. When working on integers, the result of `pow(10,2)` might be stored as 99.9999999, or 100.0000000001. Due to integer truncation, 99.9999999 gets truncated down to 99, and 100.0000000001 gets truncated down to 100.

Same goes for `pow(10,3)`, with 999.9999999, or 1000.0000000001 - which will be truncated to 999 or 1000.

You can read more about the pow function [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-function-cc/).